# insert break or space after element / in grid block

Tags: css, break

I have a grid page of album thumbnails, 2 columns and 3 rows. On the third row however I am having an issue with aligning the two items on the row...

I've been trying to insert a css break after each album thumbnail on [this page](http://www.mtf.ph/gallery-collections/galleries) ... inserting a  for example between the albums seem to fix the misalignment issue in the third row... i.e. inserting br clear all in php tpl of drupal page, for example on the fifth album thumb:

```
<br clear="all">

<div data-thmr="thmr_223" class="break-media node node-media-gallery node-teaser mg-gallery mg-teaser clearfix" id="node-136">

          <h4><a href="/gallery/philippine-development-forum-on-bangsamoro-davao-city-november-5-and-6-2014">The Philippine Development Forum on the Bangsamoro, Davao City, November 5 and 6, 2014</a></h4>

      <div data-thmr="thmr_227" class="media-collection-item-wrapper media-gallery-draggable-processed draggable"><div class="draggable-wrapper"><a class="draggable-handle">Drag</a></div><img src="/sites/all/modules/media_gallery/images/stack_bg.png" class="stack-image"><div data-thmr="thmr_231" class="media-gallery-item"><div class="top"><div class="top-inset-1"><div class="top-inset-2"></div></div></div><div class="gallery-thumb-outer"><div class="gallery-thumb-inner"><a data-thmr="thmr_232 thmr_233" class="media-gallery-thumb" href="/gallery/philippine-development-forum-on-bangsamoro-davao-city-november-5-and-6-2014"><img width="450" height="300" data-thmr="thmr_228 thmr_229 thmr_230" alt="" src="http://www.mtf.ph/sites/default/files/styles/media_gallery_thumbnail/public/media-gallery/2015the-philippine-development-forum-on-the-bangsamoro-davao-city-november-5-and-6-2014/photo-placement-1_2.jpg?itok=tgjurGwY"></a></div></div><div class="bottom"><div class="bottom-inset-1"><div class="bottom-inset-2"></div></div></div></div></div>    </div>
```

I have issue however in inserting the class in the template php page, therefore is seeking any alternatives in css instead...
 I can't seem however to get it right even with display (inline or block) or adding paddings and margins... Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Voting to close this question: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." [source](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), emphasis added

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, added more explanation and sample code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix you could try adding `min-height: 400px;` to your `.mg-col .mg-gallery.mg-teaser` class, although you would need to adjust the 400px using media queries to account for different screen widths.

Comment: Yey! Great! Yes! This fixed the issue... applying this and will check on the screen widths... Thanks for the kind assistance Sean!

Answer (score 1):

Have you condsidered using [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to align the elements?

Comment: Thanks, kajyr, yes I tried flex, but it would cause more rework sitewide... Will try options some more though using flex...